# Parsing int from DataRow cell

Tags: c#

How could int value be parsed from DataRow cell?

```
Int32.Parse(item["QuestionId"].ToString());
```

This code works, but it looks too verbose.
Also is it possible to handle DBNull values?

Comment: Just to be sure: Why do you say *parse*? Is the type of `QuestionId` actually string-like, for instance `VARCHAR`?

Comment: No, the type of QuestionId is int. But what if it was string-like?

Comment: You can use Int32.TryParse

Comment: @Anthony I'd do it with `int.Parse` in your post if it were string-like, whereas Jeppe's solution is better when it is already a numeric type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you know that it's an `int` you should just cast it accordingly, that's the safest and most efficient approach:

```
int questionId = item.Field<int>("QuestionId");  // similar to (int) item["QuestionId"]
```

The `Field` method also supports nullable types, so if it could be null:

```
int? questionId = item.Field<int?>("QuestionId");
if(questionId.HasValue) Console.Write(questionId.Value);
```

If it's actually a `string`(why?) you have to cast it to `string` and use `int.Parse`:

```
int questionId = int.Parse(item.Field<string>("QuestionId"));
```

If you really don't know what it's type is, you can use `System.Convert.ToInt32`:

```
int questionId = System.Convert.ToInt32(item["QuestionId"]);
```

Comment: .NET 2.0 does not support, does it?

Comment: @KhanhTO No, `Field` is an extension method and was added in 3.5

Comment: @KhanhTO no, the `Field<T>` method is an extension method which is only available in .NET 3.5+

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, `int? questionId = item.Field<int?>("QuestionId");` is this safe against `DbNull` value also?

Answer (score 7):

If what is put into that cell is actually just an `int`, use:

```
(int)item["QuestionId"]
```

Otherwise, check the runtime type of the value `item["QuestionId"]`, if it is a `byte` for example, use `(byte)item["QuestionId"]`. If you're not sure, then:

```
Convert.ToInt32(item["QuestionId"])
```

will probably work, but that's less elegant.

Comment: @Wouter Huysentruit: will an exception be thrown if there is a NULL value?

Comment: If `null` must not throw an exception, consider `(int?)item["QuestionId"]`.