# Casting DataRow value into float

Tags: c#, casting, datarow

I'm working with `DataRow` and I want to divide every value in the row with a number(taken from a cell from the same row). I've been searching ways to convert the values into float, like from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719016/parsing-int-from-datarow-cell) thread, but casting gives me "Specified cast is not valid" error.

```
List<DataTable> tblsol = new List<DataTable>();
DataTable now = tblsol.Last();

while (true)
        {
            DataRow fb = now.Rows[v];
            DataRow fb2 = now.Rows[w];
            float akun = (float)fb[fb.Table.Columns.Count - 1] /
            (float)fb[u];
            if (akun > (float)fb2[fb2.Table.Columns.Count - 1] /
            (float)fb2[u])
            {
                if (w == now.Rows.Count - 1) { v = w; break; }
                else { v++; w++; }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (w == now.Rows.Count - 1) { break; }
                else { w++; }

            }
        }

        DataRow bk = now.Rows[v];

        float angkun = Convert.ToSingle(bk[u]);
        for (int dc = 1; dc < now.Columns.Count;dc++)
        {
            bk[dc] = Convert.ToSingle(bk[dc]) / angkun;
        }
```

I used 2 methods to convert the value into float (using `Convert.toSingle` and casting), but both ways gave me error. Is there anything else I can do? Or maybe is there something wrong in my code?
p.s. `tblSol` is not empty and all variables are already declared.

Comment: Have you perchance tried casting the column  value to a Decimal first?

Comment: Decimal works, thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I'll post that as an answer. Wasn't sure if that was the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, try casting the relevant columns to `Decimal` first. It is one of the explicitly supported DataTypes when accessing data from columns of DataRow instances; the valid types are listed in the [MSDN DataColumn Reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try float.Parse, but you need to convert the datarow to dynamic/string type for it to be compatible:

```
var test = (dynamic)fb[fb.Table.Columns.Count - 1];
float boat = float.Parse(test);
```

Or something similar using `float.Parse`

Answer (score 1):

You can try after converting it to `String` like this,

```
float akun = float.Parse(fb[fb.Table.Columns.Count - 1].ToString()) /
        float.Parse(fb[u].ToString());
```